# Ошибка в пакете russiantime

Tags: golang, время

Пытаюсь компилировать:

```
time = time.Now()
ruTime.Time = russiantime.Time
ruTime.FormatRU("%YYYY %YYY %YY %Y,")
```

но ошибка в самом пакете:

> ParseFloat redeclared during import "strconv"at line 5 col 1  previous
>   declaration during import "math/big" (build)

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с таким и как это решить?

Comment: С этим вам скорее к автору пакета надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мы об [одном и том же](https://github.com/t0pep0/russiantime), то проблема в том, что импорт в пакете `russiantime` организован с помещением экспортируемых идентификаторов сторонних пакетов в файловый блок, при этом, в двух пакетах нашлись одинаковые идентификаторы (видимо, когда-то это было не так). Если проще, во всём виноваты точки:

```
import (
    . "math/big"
    . "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)
```

Чинится не самым приятным образом, но, в силу мизерного объёма модуля, не так страшно, точки убираются, использования идентификаторов зачищаются пакетными префиксами, [получается нехитрый патч.](http://roman.khimov.ru/external/russiantime-import.patch)

---

[Патч был принят автором](https://github.com/t0pep0/russiantime/pull/1), так что актуальная версия будет работать сама по себе.